# Concat two columns with one column null, that time why i am getting null value?

Tags: mysql

Concat two columns with one column null, that time why I am getting null value?

```
SELECT CONCAT(u.first_name,u.last_name) FROM users AS u;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try this query.

```
SELECT CONCAT(IFNULL(u.first_name,''),IFNULL(u.last_name,'')) FROM users AS u;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
SELECT CONCAT(ifnull(u.first_name, ''), ifnull(u.last_name, '')) FROM users AS u;
```